# mysql count the number of unique id's in the column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

here is my query

```
SELECT
  pa.products_attributes_id,
  pa.products_id,
  pa.options_id
FROM products_attributes pa
LEFT JOIN products_description pd
  ON pa.products_id = pd.products_id
  AND pd.language_id = '1'
LEFT JOIN products_attributes_groups pag
  ON pa.products_attributes_id = pag.products_attributes_id
WHERE pa.products_id = '109'
GROUP BY pa.products_attributes_id
ORDER BY pa.attribute_sort
```

[image]

As you can see in the last column `options_id` there are 3 unique option id's (i.e 2, 13 and 1)

what i want to achieve is count the number of unique id's in the option_id column. In the above result set the query should return me 3 (as there are 3 unique option_ids 2, 13 and 1).
I don't have issue if this count comes in new temprary column with all the rows of the result set

P.S: I do not want to change `GROUP BY pa.products_attributes_id` as I need it in fetching data

EDIT:using `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT options_id) FROM products_attributes ) AS options_id_count` the result set is now 12 which is wrong (it should be 3)
[image]

Comment: Are you looking for your current result set but with an extra column for distinct option count?

Comment: Post the required result. Once you have `GROUP BY` the `COUNT` is performed for each group

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As you can see in the screenshot there are 4 times 2, 7 times 13 and 3 times 1 in  the options_id column. I only need to count the unique integers in this column. In the above exampole it will give me answer of 3 which I need to show in the new column with all the 14 rows of the above result set

Comment: your query seems incorrect because you have wrong `GROUP BY`

Comment: @OtoShavadze I can not change the group by column as I need the records in the format I am getting now. I just need a way to count the number of unique entities in the options_id column keeping the current group by column

Comment: `SELECT
  pa.products_attributes_id,
  pa.products_id,
  pa.options_id...` with `...GROUP BY pa.products_attributes_id` is incorrect expression. Suppose you have `options_id=1` and`options_id=2` for same `products_attributes_id`, which one `options_id` should choose database, when you grouping by `products_attributes_id`?

Comment: Why the two LEFT JOIN in the query?

Comment: Your query makes no sense. You outer join `products_description` and `products_attributes_groups`, but don't use their data, so all you do is duplicate your `products_attributes` records. Then you group by `products_attributes_id` to get rid of those duplicates again. What the heck? Your query does exactly the same as a simple `SELECT products_attributes_id, products_id, options_id FROM products_attributes WHERE products_id = '109' ORDER BY attribute_sort` only obfuscated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT options_id) as field_name` :)

Comment: I already have tried this.. this will count each row only and give me result of 1 in each row

Comment: It's normal, you can't use an aggregation function for each row because you have only one value to count for each row. You should do a second query to count, or alternatively, join the result of a subquery for every row you got, but i don't like this solution, i prefer the second query. Sorry for my horrible english :P
Note that the second alternative is not an elegant solution, because you are doing a subquery for each row of your result-set, and this affect your query performance. Use a second query!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `<REST_OF_YOUR_QUERY>` is the part of your query beginning with `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
  pa.products_attributes_id,
  pa.products_id,
  pa.options_id,
  (
     SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT options_id) 
     FROM products_attributes
     <REST_OF_YOUR_QUERY>
  ) option_count
FROM products_attributes pa
<REST_OF_YOUR_QUERY>
```

Comment: I have edited the question and attached the results screenshot by using your sql modification. it gives me 12 instead of 3.. have a look at the screenshot in  the edits.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> the query should return me 3

That is just the distinct count of `options_id` in `products_attributes` for `products_id` 109:

```
select count(distinct options_id)
from products_attributes 
where products_id = 109;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to make two passes over the data (once to extract the results and once to count distinct option_id values) you might drop the query into a with and just reference it twice.  Oracle will optimize this into a temporary GTT and only read the source data once.

```
WITH d AS
 (SELECT pa.products_attributes_id,
         pa.products_id,
         pa.options_id
    FROM products_attributes pa
    LEFT JOIN products_description pd
      ON pa.products_id = pd.products_id
     AND pd.language_id = '1'
    LEFT JOIN products_attributes_groups pag
      ON pa.products_attributes_id = pag.products_attributes_id
   WHERE pa.products_id = '109'
   GROUP BY pa.products_attributes_id
   ORDER BY pa.attribute_sort)
SELECT d.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d.options_id)
          FROM d)
  FROM d;
```